# Wie sagt man "I don't mind" auf höflicher Art und Weise?

Tags: translation, expression

> Do you mind if I go out with Jana tonight?
>
> No, I don't.

Macht es dir nichts aus, wenn ich heute Abend ausgehe?

Nein, das macht mir nichts aus.

Bei dict.cc habe ich diesen Ausdruck gefunden, ich bin mir damit unsicher, ob er höflich ist. Es gibt einen anderen Ausdruck auf der Liste, aber ich denke nicht, dass er zu diesem Kontext passt : Das ist mir egal!

Comment: Mehrere Nutzer (inkl. ich) verstehen diese Frage anders, als die akzeptierte Antwort es nahelegt. Kannst Du bitte die Frage klarer machen oder dazu Stellung nehmen? Bis dahin schließe ich die Frage, um weitere Antworten und mehr Chaos zu vermeiden.

Comment: Wie wäre ein [edit] des Titels: *Wie sagt man “do you mind” auf höfliche Art und Weise?* - dann passen die Antworten wieder.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Die Frage ist klar formuliert und gut verständlich. Sie lautet: »Wie sagt man “I dont mind” auf höflicher Art und Weise?« Leider beantwortet keine der beiden Antworten diese Frage, sondern behandeln einen Aspekt, der gar nicht gefragt war. Das ist aber nicht der klar formulierten Frage anzukreiden, sondern den Antworten. Der Fragesteller hat nichts falsch gemacht, die beiden Antwort-Autoren hingegen schon. Wenn du also kraft deiner Position als Moderator etwas schließt, dann bitte die beiden Antworten, nicht diese Frage!

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: *Der Fragesteller hat nichts falsch gemacht* – Der Fragesteller hat eine der Antworten akzeptiert, was stark nahelegt, dass er wollte, dass die Frage so verstanden wurde, wie diese Antwort sie verstanden hat. Wenn er dies nicht getan hätte, gäbe ich Dir völlig recht.

Comment: @Takkat: Das will der Fragesteller aber nicht wissen. Im Dialog »Macht dir das etwas aus? - Nein, das macht mir nichts aus.« will er eine höfliche Formulierung für die Antwort »Nein, das macht mir nichts aus.« haben. Und das geht, meiner Auffassung nach, auch klar aus der Frage hervor. Leider konzentrieren sich hier alle (aus mir unerklärlichen Gründen) auf die Frage »Macht dir das etwas aus?«. Danach hat aber niemand gefragt.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: doch, das wollte er wissen, denn sonst hätte er hoffentlich nicht eine der Antworten als richtig akzeptiert. Uns geht es darum, dass diese Q&A auch zukünftigen Besuchern weiter hilft. Das ist derzeit nicht der Fall.

Comment: Die einfachste Lösung wäre, die Frage wieder aufzumachen und jemand erklärt sich bereit, eine ordentliche Antwort auf die eigentliche Frage zu erstellen. Die wird dann wohl nicht mehr akzeptiert, kann aber wenigstens hochgevotet werden, um zu signalisieren, was die Antwort *gewesen wäre*

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Ich würde den Konjunktiv präferieren:
"Würde es dir etwas ausmachen, wenn ich heute Nacht mit Jana ausgehe?"

Comment: Hmm. Ist das eine Antwort auf die Frage? @DerPolyglott33 Warum hast du die Antwort akzeptiert? Sie beantwortet doch deine Frage nach "I don't mind" gar nicht?

Comment: Warum sollte die Antwort die Frage nicht beantworten?

Comment: Lies mal die Überschrift. Da steht?

Comment: Man liest für gewöhnlich aber nicht nur die Überschrift, sondern auch den Inhalt. Und im Inhalt wrd klar ersichtlich, dass er eine höflichere Variante des Zitats will, die er bekommen hat. Sonst hätte er ja wohl nicht meine Antwort als hilfreich ausgezeichnet, oder? Hat er aber, also war es für ihn sehr wohl eine Antwort. Und da ist es vollkommen egal, was du davon hältst.

Comment: @Reese: *Und im Inhalt wrd klar ersichtlich, dass er eine höflichere Variante des Zitats will, die er bekommen hat.* – Woran machst Du das fest? Im Hautptteil der Frage gibt es nur einen Hinweis darum, um welchen der beiden Sätze es geht und das ist die Erwähnung von »Das ist mir egal!«, welche zum zweiten Teil passt.

Comment: Ich weiß nicht, was ihr hier diskutiert. Was ist das überhaupt für eine Art? Ich habe geantwortet, er hat die Antwort akzeptiert. Genau DARAN mache ich das fest. Fertig. Könnt ihr nicht einfach akzeptieren, dass die Antwort wohl ausreichend genug war? Ihr seid nicht seine Sprecher.

Comment: @Reese Es gibt keinen Grund, aggressiv zu reagieren. Wir interessieren uns nur dafür, das spätere Sucher mit derselben Frage auch eine gescheite Antwort  finden. Das ist hier zumindestens sehr zweifelhaft.

Comment: Wenn es aggressiv rüberkam, entschuldige ich mich. War nicht meine Intention. Ein Fragesteller stellt seine Frage nicht für die Allgemeinheit, sondern für sich. Er hat seine gestellt und wohl seine Antwort erhalten. Wenn andere andere Fragen haben, stellen sie auch ihre Fragen, sofern ihre persönliche Frage nicht schon woanders beantwortet wurde. Da kann meinetwegen Merkel kommen und sagen "Die Antwort hat aber nicht meine Erwartungen erfüllt", das wäre vollkommen irrelevant, weil der Fragesteller die Antwort auf seine Frage erhalten hat, sonst hätte er sie ja wohl nicht ausgezeichnet.

Comment: Warum also zweifelhaft? Warum zweifelt ihr an, dass der Fragesteller seine Antwort erhalten hat, wenn er meine Antwort selbst bestätigt hat? Hier ist garnichts zweifelhaft. Für euch ist es vielleicht zweifelhaft, aber nicht für ihn und genau darauf kommt es an. Auf nichts Anderes.

Comment: Reese: "Ein Fragesteller stellt seine Frage nicht für die Allgemeinheit, sondern für sich." - im gesamten Stack-Exchange-Netzwerk ist der Grundgedanke, dass Fragen und deren Antworten gerade *nicht* nur für den Fragesteller nützlich sein sollen. Genau deshalb wird insgesamt auf die Qualität (Verständlichkeit usw.) von Fragen geachtet, halbwegs konsequent getaggt, um die Auffindbarkeit zu verbessern, deswegen sind Duplikate von Fragen und vorgefertigte Standardantworten nicht erwünscht und auch zu spezielle Fragen (die außer dem Fragesteller vermutlich niemandem helfen würden - auf ...

Comment: ... Sprachseiten wie dieser sind das beispielsweise Bitten um Übersetzungen konkreter Texte) werden normalerweise geschlossen.

Answer (score -3):

Ja, der Ausdruck ist höflich.

Allerdings würde ich ihn nicht in der negierten Form benutzen, und stattdessen

```
Macht es dir (et-)was aus, wenn ich heute Abend ausgehe?
```

Das macht die Antwort mit "nein" dann auch logisch eindeutig.

(Und wenn man ganz pingelig sein will, ist es vielleicht doch ein wenig unhöflich, von vorneherein anzunehmen, dass es der anderen Person nichts ausmacht, und sie quasi dazu zwingt, dir zu widersprechen...)

Comment: Hmm. Ist das eine Antwort auf die Frage?

Comment: @tofro: hm, finde ich schon. Der OP wollte wissen, ob sein Vorschlag höflich war - und meiner Meinung nach ist er das. Allerdings nicht ganz optimal, von daher habe ich noch einen Verbesserungsvorschlag hinzugefügt. Ich sehe ehrlich gesagt das Problem nicht - und anscheinend bin ich da auch nicht alleine.

Comment: @Gerhard:Sehe ich ja auch so. Aber die Herren und / oder Damen hier glauben ja selbst der Bestätigung des Fragestellers nicht, dass unsere beiden Antworten korrekt sind. Stattdessen reiten sie auf der Frage rum, obwohl sie durch die Bestätigung meines Posts als korrekte Antwort sowieso erledigt ist. Tut mir Leid, aber so etwas kann ich nicht nachvollziehen. Wer, wenn nicht der Fragesteller, wird wohl wissen, ob seine eigene Frage korrekt beantwortet wurde? Haltet ihr ihn für blöd?